# Easy remote support solution for Windows PCs from Linux

Tags: windows, remote

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remote assistance Linux to Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/91156/remote-assistance-linux-to-windows)

When installing Linux for friends and family, I usually leave a script that sets up a remote SSH tunnel to my server, so that I can connect back to them via SSH even when they are behind regular DSL firewalls. On Windows, however, I am not sure what solution is the best and easiest way for me to offer remote support. A VPN does seem like a terrible amount of trouble. Does anyone have experience on an easy and free solution for this?

Comment: The "Remote assistance Linux to Windows" question (http://superuser.com/questions/91156/remote-assistance-linux-to-windows) doesn't exist any more (error 404). Can somebody update the link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/index.aspx) has good cross-platform support.  If you just want a VPN, [LogMeIn Hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi/) is great.

Comment: TeamViewer is probably the best tool to give "over the shoulder" help over the internet. It is somewhat of an industry standard by now, a lot of help desks require you to install that, even.

Answer (score 3):

[LogMeIn](http://www.logmein.com) have some brilliant products. You can install LogMeIn free which will allow you to connect and remote control at any time (when they have internet connectivity). Or if you want ad-hoc then [join.me](http://join.me) is briliant (no registration even required).

L

Comment: I've been using LogMeIn (Pro/Free w/ Central) on a regular basis for the last 6 months and am pretty impressed with the product.  Since it uses a web interface it should be managable from linux with no issues.